# NASM matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I was writing an AVX matrix-vector multiplication function in C but realized an instruction I needed was not implemented in GCC, so I saw that as a golden opportunity to learn some x86 assembly. I first wrote a routine in MIPS assembly and then tried translating it. My code is not working, I get segfault and I have no idea why. If I remove the two `jnz` in the code, it works, but I don't understand why they would have any impact. Does this type of jump destroy registers that I'm using?

EDIT: It appears that the first two instructions in `main` don't set `rdi` to 2, but rather to `0x1000000002`, which causes trouble later. Why isn't 2 loaded?

EDIT2: Got it. As @rkhb pointed out, using rXX registers loads more data than I intended. I changed the registers to the 32-bit ones (where applicable), which solved the segfault problem. However, now the program printed 0,0. This was because the loop advances eax by 8 (in the below example), but doesn't subtract that amount before returning. Thus, the values are in `addr` and `addr+4`, but the pointer returned is `addr+8`.

```
; nasm -felf64 filename.asm
; gcc filename.o

    global  main
    extern  printf

    section .data
N:  dd 2            ; dimension
a:  dd 1, 2, 3, 4       ; matrix
b:  dd 1, 2         ; vector
format: db "%d", 10, 0

    section .bss
c:  resb 8          ; reserve 8B

    section .text
main:
    ; set up arguments
    lea rdi, [N]    ; fix: change regs to edi, etc
    mov rdi, [rdi]
    lea rsi, [a]
    lea rdx, [b]
    lea rcx, [c]

    call    matvec      ; c = a*b

    ; print results
    mov rsi, [rax]
    mov rdi, format
    push    rax
    mov rax, 0
    call    printf      ; print c[0], should be 5
    pop rax
    add rax, 4
    mov rsi, [rax]
    mov rdi, format
    mov rax, 0
    call    printf      ; print c[1], should be 11

    ret

; rdi = N, rsi = int*, rdx = int*, rcx = int*
matvec:
    mov rax, rcx    ; rax = c
    mov R14, rdi    ; r14 = N
    mov R15, R14
    shl R15, 2      ; r15 = 4*N
    xor R8, R8      ; i = 0
    xor R9, R9      ; j = 0
    xor R10, R10    ; sum = 0

loop:
    mov R11, [rsi]  ; r11 = *a
    mov R12, [rdx]  ; r12 = *b
    imul    R11, R12    ; r11 *= r12
    add R10, R11    ; r10 += r11
    add rsi, 4      ; a++
    add rdx, 4      ; b++
    add R9, 1       ; j++
    cmp R14, R9
    jnz loop        ; loop while r14-r9 = N-j != 0

    mov [rax], R10  ; *c = sum
    xor R10, R10    ; sum = 0
    xor R9, R9      ; j = 0 on every i loop
    sub rdx, R15    ; b -= 4*N
    add rax, 4      ; c++
    add R8, 1       ; i++
    cmp R14, R8
    jnz loop        ; loop while r14-r8 = N-i != 0

    sub rax, R15    ; fix: subtract 4*N from return pointer
    ret
```

Comment: `mov rdi, [rdi]` loads 8 bytes. But `N:  dd 2` is just 4 bytes big. change `dd` to `dq`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that might have something to do with it and so I made the more cumbersome change, namely changed all regs from rax to eax etc. Now it works but after return to main, the values in rax are zeroed, or rather, what rax points to is zeroed.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, you should post it as an answer, rather than as an edit to your question.

Comment: Alright. I didn't think it was necessary really but ok I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data is declared as 4 bytes, but 8-byte registers (`rax` etc) are used for holding the data. When loading the data into these registers you will then your data in the low 4 bytes and garbage in the high 4 bytes. To avoid this, either change the declarations so that 8-byte data is declared (using `dq`), or use the 4-byte registers instead (`eax` etc).

Fixing that will take care of the problem with segmentation fault, but the program will return the wrong result. The result is intended to be stored at memory address `c`, whose value is held in `rax`. In the above code, that address is incremented by 4 bytes twice; while the calculated values are stored in `c[0]` and `c[1]`, the address returned in `rax` is actually `&c[2]`. Thus, before returning to `main` you need to decrement `rax` by 8, or by `4*N` in general.

EDIT: You can inspect registers using the GNU debugger, read [this](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/nasm.shtml) guide.